# Auto populate the email and password in the web browser when user checks remember me

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, auto-populate

I have got an requirement to auto populate email and password to be auto populated in the login form, if the user is checked the remember me check box in the user login form.

As i have checked through some documents and googling i got some of the understanding that this is the browser behavior. And is to be the user acceptance of the browsers automatic popup to be used to get the user acceptance to save the user info.

I came to know that the devise is making the browser to store the values in cache and managing the session to be continued even the browser is closed.

As I have to work on that can any some one of you please show me the right path or suggest me to achieve this if it is possible.

Comment: If you implement your app properly, it should not be possible (because you wouldn't have passwords lying around in clear text). You're right, it's the job of client's browser (or its extensions). Nothing to do for you here.

Comment: What is the requirement __exactly__? Auto-populate password field _or_ not log-out user after he closes the tab/browser?

Comment: Hello Serigo, Thanks for the reply,

My requirement is to auto populate email and password to the respective fields. when the user come to the login page even after sign-out as he has checked the remember me check box, last time when he was logged in from the same browser.

Comment: What is name of the site you're developing, so that I will know to never even visit it? This requirement goes against all best practices in password management.

Comment: Also you (or rather people who assign you tasks) don't understand the purpose of "remember me". It is to maintain user session across browser restarts. It should most definitely **not** result in user password being stored somewhere in clear text (especially on client's computer)

Comment: Yep, I too understand that, it will be the strong lapse of the security, I just want to make it clear and more over for some browsers like chrome, which will store the data in the browser database, as it uses sqllite if i am correct, i want to make a confirmation weather if we can do any thing with that, to solve the requirement, as we will do using local db in the mobile browsers or aps

Comment: Now that you've been warned, it is possible to store clear text password in some kind of local storage (cookie, browser db and the like)

Comment: Ok sure, I got the information, if we need to do that we need to compromise with the security things, even we doesn't want to compromise with the security stuff though.

Please let me know if any chances to store the same in some encrypted format.

Thanks for the info - @SergioTulentsev

Comment: Encryption won't matter, as _something_ will need to be able to decrypt the password. This means that either password will be sent as clear text over the wire (server decrypts it) or the client side will have all the tools to do the decryption itself (and so would the possible attacker)

Comment: Thanks @SergioTulentsev for your replies.

From any side it is vulnerable to attackers, so it can't be done considering the security .

Answer (score 0):

Usually with username and password field we have remember me:

```
<%= label_tag :remember_me %>
<%= check_box_tag :remember_me, 1, params[:remember_me] %>
<%= submit_tag "Log in" %>
```

When user hits submit button if we call login action then usually it looks like this:

```
def login
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:username])
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
    if params[:remember_me]
      cookies.permanent[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
    else
      cookies[:auth_token] = user.auth_token  
    end
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"
  else
    flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
    render "new"
  end
end
```

Now as your user wants to auto populate the username and password rather than auto login. Then I think you should not permanently save the token to cookies like this: `cookies.permanent[:auth_token] = user.auth_token` rather than put it like this `cookies[:auth_token] = user.auth_token`. And let the browser auto fill the login form.

```
def login
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:username])
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
    if params[:remember_me]
      cookies[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
    else
      cookies[:auth_token] = user.auth_token  
    end
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"
  else
    flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
    render "new"
  end
end
```

If you don't want to put it on the hand of browser then you can do the following, though I DON'T THINK YOU SHOULD DO THAT:

```
<%= form_tag sessions_path do %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :email %>
    <%= text_field_tag :email, @user.email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :password %>
    <%= password_field_tag @user.password %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :remember_me %>
    <%= check_box_tag :remember_me, 1,remember_me %>
  </div>  
  <div class="actions"><%= submit_tag "Log in" %></div>
```

Comment: Hello Sadaf, Thanks for the reply.

As i want to fill the email and password field of the form, Even if i save them in the cookie, i think i can't populate them to the fields of the form,which is the exact requirement

Comment: I think you can. just pull them from cookie and change the value of your from!

Comment: Yes, we even shouldn't store the password in the clear text in the browser, in the form of cookies